# WP_Query mixe post and page attributes

Tags: wp-query

I am working on a website developed by someone else (it's a bit messy).
Now I have to make a small widget to let the users search for some of the content that has been created.
I need to be able to make a search on posts and pages, but also define several carac to the search.
For example mixing a search for a posts that belong to a dedicated parent AND pages which belong to a specific category.

I tried something like that :

```
$arguments = array(
        'post_type'=> array('post','page'),
        'post_parent__in' => array('58'),
        'category_name' => 'case-study',
        'order_by'=>'DESC',
        'posts_per_page'=>'20'
    );
```

But I think I'm probably missing an OR case somewhere since I don't receive any results.

I have looked at the codex but isn't able to find a correct search for my query.

Can somebody help please?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you mean pages with parent and posts from category ;) But there is no easy way to do this using WP_Query. The conditions are combined with "or", so you won't get anything from that query (there are no posts with such parent and no pages in given category).

Comment: So posts that are in a category but don't have that parent AND posts that have that parent but don't have that category? I don't believe that can be done with a single query, aka 2 mutually exclusive queries in 1 go, not with `WP_Query`, maybe if you had an elastic search setup. i suspect the problem here is data structure, but there's not enough context to be able to tell, e.g. I don't now why you want this. It could be that you're abusing the way posts and pages work to do something that would be better done with a custom post type and a custom taxonomy, but I can't tell

Comment: Hey guys thank you for answering. Indeed I have a bad structure. I don't know why some contents are build as posts, and some are pages where they should have a similar structure, but as I mentioned I'm grabbing a website build by someone else and I have around 200 articles which are build this way (and I would prefer to avoid rebuilding everything right now :D). Maybe I can try to make 2 different queries and just mix the results in one array... Thanks for confirming that there is no way to have everything in just one request.